# Paypal NVP refund

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I am trying to refund the amount using paypal nvp.

Is it possible to refund a amount which is paid completely and txn_type= cart ?

I am getting the error 10009 "Unable to refund this type of transaction"

Comment: Are you using the Refund API or the RefundTransaction API?

Comment: I am using RefundTransaction API